# How to communicate from a embedded pdf to the browser

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a webpage that has pdf embedded in it, by a object tag.
Now I want to call a javascript method , present in the webpage, from pdf.

Basically, I want to communicate from pdf to browser. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
Using a javascript API, `hostContainer.postMessage` provided by adobe, we can communicate between a hostContainer i.e. a browser and pdf.

For more information please check
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf